# Is there a better way to remove duplicates from two dicts based on certain conditions?

Tags: python

For example:

```
m = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
n = {'a': ('jack', 'true'),
     'b': ('tom', 'true'),
     'c': ('jack', 'false')}

new_dict = {}
for key, key_info in n.items():
    if key in m:
        name = key_info[0]
        # If name is already in new_dict
        if name in new_dict:
            if new_dict[name][1] < m[key]:
                new_dict[name] = (key, m[key])
        else:  # Name not in new_dict
            new_dict[name] = (key, m[key])

new_dict = dict(new_dict.values())
```

The output of new_dict would be:

```
{'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

I want to remove elements from 'm' where:

1. find elements with the same name, which is stored in the 'value' of the  2nd dict 'n'
2. Because both 'a' & 'c' have the same name 'jack' and c's value 3 is greater than '1', so {'a': 1} is deleted.

My above code works but looks bad. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: "The output of new_dict would be:" I can't understand where the `'d'` key is supposed to come from (and I don't get one when I test the code).

Comment: The code shown cannot possibly generate that output

Comment: No 'd', sorry for the given example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make name-key pairs from `n`, then sort them according to the key's corresponding value in `m`:

```
names_and_keys = [(v[0], k) for k, v in n.items()]
names_and_keys.sort(key=lambda nk: m[nk[1]])
```

Then build a dict from those pairs. Since they were sorted so that e.g. the `c` key comes after the `a` key (since `m['c'] > m['a']`), `'jack'` will be mapped to `'c'` (that pair will overwrite the original as each pair is used to build the dict).

```
lookup = dict(names_and_keys)
```

Finally, the values of that dict are the keys that should be retained from `m` (similar to how the original code works, except that we still have to get the values from the original `m`).

```
m = {k:m[k] for k in lookup.values()}
```